# How can I make a new mail alert in Outlook display an option to Move instead of Flag or Delete?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

When an Outlook [new mail alert](http://office.microsoft.com/global/images/default.aspx?AssetID=ZA010776241033) appears, it has two buttons: Flag and Delete.

Usually I don't want to do either of those.  What I want to do is Move the message to a different folder.  Is there a way I can get rid of one of those default buttons and replace it with the Move button?

Comment: In the end, it turned out that an even better solution was to just disable all e-mail notifications.  Less disruption while I work!

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can set up rules that can move all new emails to folders upon them arriving.

Click Tools > "Rules and Alerts"

and you should be able to set it from here

Comment: That's not what I want to do.  I want to see the e-mail in the alert and then decide whether to move it...and then be able to move it right from the alert.